# Sdcard not recognized after formatting

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I own a mtk phone, a Wiko Rainbow (Wiko -- a french low cost phone brand) and I recently got a quite awfuling problem: the sdcard is no more recognized afetr having been formatted
The sdcard of the phone was no more recognized on any PC for some time. So I decided to format it so this issue be fixed.
Then I did.

But now, the phone doesn't recognized the sdcard at all. No way to see it in phone browser. the sdacrd doesn't appear in Settings> memory too.
I tried many kind of formatting : fast formatting, or not with Windows 8.1, I also delete the FAT 32 partition on sdcard, then recreate it in FAT32... No more success...

So I tried to access trough adb but no success...I get a strange error I've never seen when trying to cd to usual mouting point of sdcard (/mnt/sdcard1/)
The error: Transport endpoint is not connected.
Any idea so I recover my sdcard please ? that's really boring !

Thanks in advance

The phone has a stock recovery, is running android 4.4.2 KitKat, and is rooted.

[Edit] tested with an other Wiko Rainbow (which had some sdcard problem too) and same issue !! Exactly the same ! sdcard no more recognized with "Transport endpoint is not connected." issue trough adb ! I precise I used an other sdcard, but same brand that the first

So, to resume we have 2 phones Wiko Rainbow, 2 Samsung class 10 SDHC card, and exactly the same issue for the 2 devices ! Problem can't be software, because it's been updated some days ago for the both smartphones, and the problem didn't solve.

So I tend to think the samsung sdcard may be defective, due to too many R/W perhaps ? I have no idea.... Can somenone enlight me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which software did you use to format the card?  Were you using a built-in or stand-alone card reader?

Comment: Hello, I used the basic format software of Windows fisrt (right clic > format > ), then I used Minitool partition software.  I used a SDHC card reader

Comment: I have found that any time I have formatted an sdcard in windows, android has an issue reading it. If you can, use linux (or a mac) to format the card, or have android format it. You can use a Linux "LiveCD" to boot in to linux to format. But really the easiest way would be to format it in android, on the device.

Comment: Hello, 
First, have a great year :)  (it's 00:33 where I live). I hesitated to format with gparted because having very hard problem with the last time I formated a sdcard for Android. But I will try this, thanks for your advice. I hope it will resolve that issue... :)